# Upside Down Loft (Weeds)

Tags: plot-explanation, weeds

How did everything in the loft get upside down?

**Weeds:  Season 7:

Episode: 9 (Cats! Cats! Cats!) &

Episode: 10 (System Overhead)**

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCUl0mSGRtI?

Comment: obviously Andy and Silas did it; are you asking for the mechanical details of the prank?

Comment: @MikeEdenfield Yeah, it was like the whole building was upside down; was trippy..

Comment: A whole lot of krazy glue. http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/237/489/237489983_200.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Bouncey House, the rival drug dealers did it as a "look how easy we mess with you" warning. the neighbour comments later that there was a lot of noise coming from the bike shop all night. a ladder, a drill, a hammer, a wicked sense of humour... all the ingredients